# How to use a timer to display content?

Tags: c#, wpf, timer

I am having issues with getting my timer to change content on a window.

I initialize my timer by:

```
timeOutTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(15000);
            timeOutTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(timeOutEvent);
            timeOutTimer.Enabled = true;
            timeOutTimer.AutoReset = false;
            timeOutTimer.Start();
```

I have a ContentControl which is Hidden.

When the timer passes 15 seconds it should change the visibility of the ContentControl

```
private void timeOutEvent(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    TicketContent.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    Console.WriteLine("TIMED OUT");
    timeOutTimer.Stop();

}
```

I am getting an exception :
System.InvalidOperationException

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What line is throwing the exception?

Comment: TicketContent.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use DispatcherTimer

```
timer = new DispatcherTimer(
    TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15), 
    DispatcherPriority.Background, 
    TimeoutEvent, 
    this.Dispatcher);

timer.Start();
```

Comment: For the third argument, do I just place my method as my call back function?

Comment: Thanks again! Btw, do you know if it continues and keeps calling that function, or does it stop after 1 call

Answer (score 0):

When you start a timer, it begins on a separate non UI thread. As it is in a separate thread it cannot access elements in the UI thread. A delegate in combination with a Dispatcher.BeginInvoke() method will allow you to modify the properties of UI elements.

```
    private void timeOutEvent(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        TicketContent.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new InvokeDelegate(TimeOutEvent));
        Console.WriteLine("TIMED OUT");
        timeOutTimer.Stop();
    }

    public delegate void InvokeDelegate();


    private void TimeOutEvent()
    {
        TicketContent.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }
```

Comment: I can't seem to find InvokeDelegate, is that for WPF?

Comment: Yes, the method is in .NET 3.5.